# Building symbol table using hash table

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to build a symbol table using hash table. The general idea is

```
int alpha;
2 int beta;
3 alpha = 0; // the alpha declared in line 1
4 beta = 0; // the beta declared in line 2
5 gamma = 0; // Error! gamma hasn't been declared.
6 {
7 int beta; // This beta shadows the one declared in line 2.
8 int gamma;
9 alpha = 0; // the alpha declared in line 1
10 beta = 0; // the beta declared in line 7
11 gamma = 0; // the gamma declared in line 8
12 }
```

and so on. You only can use vector, list, stack, and queue library and try to make it as fast as it can.
My idea was on each scope, I declare hashtable in the list and save all the information to that table, and whenever I have new scope, I push_back new hashtable into the list.
But it seems like this approach is very slow when the program is looking for on item that is out of scope far far away since you have to look for each scope to find the item.

Do you guys have any idea to implement this scope that is way faster than this? It should be way faster cause my implementation is slower than the "slow version they provided"

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Have just one hash table for everything, and a stack of context objects. Push a new object on the stack whenever you see a '{'. When you shadow a variable, remember the old symbol in your context object and just overwrite it in the hash table. When you see a '}' and pop the context, restore the symbols you have remembered there.

Comment: Will this be faster than the method I did??

Comment: @kelly-song Well it should be somewhat faster, since you only search in one hash table. In any case you should profile your program in order to see where's the bottleneck.

Comment: I'm sorry.. What is profile my program? and bottleneck? New to this stuff ;p

Comment: @kelly-song Profiling means to find execution time characteristic (a profile) of the program, using a special tool called _profiler_. A bottleneck is a code fragment that dominates execution time, i.e. the program spends more time executing that fragment than any other part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

When I did this, I used the hash table for symbols, not for entities.
For each symbol, I had a list of entities.  Each entity was in two
lists, one from the symbol, and the second from the scope.  The list
from the symbol was managed like a stack: when I accessed a symbol, the
entity in scope was always the first in the list.  When I left a scope,
I walked its list of entities, and removed them from the list of
symbols.

This was some time ago, before the STL (and even before C++); I
implemented everything by hand, and used invasive chaining for the
lists, with the algorithm so designed that I could remove an element
from a list without knowing where the list itself was.  (This is
relatively easy with hand written double linked lists.)  Today, with the
STL (and with the importance of locality of access), I'd probably simply
put a pointer to the head of the list in each entity.  With the STL, and
considerations of locality, I'd probably use `std::vector` for the list
for each entity (the symbol table thus being a map of `std::string` to
`std::vector`).  Symbol table lookup, once the entry is found, is simply
calling `back()` on the vector (after checking that it isn't empty, if
you don't purge the entry when the vector becomes empty).  When you
create new entity, in a new scope, you call `push_back` on the vector,
and save the address of the vector in an entry for the scope (a
`std::stack` of `std::vector<std::vector<Entity>*>`); when leaving
scope, you iterate over the vector at the top of this stack, calling
`pop_back` on all of its entries, then pop it off the stack.  (And
obviously, when entering a new scope, you `push` a new empty vector onto
the scope stack.)

Maintaining the double list means that for all operations, you know
exactly which element to access, without having to iterate over
anything; there's never any access to an entity to see if it's the one
you're looking for.  In my day, it was fairly straightforward, but a lot
of code, requiring considerable care, and my implemention probably
wouldn't be that fast today, because of poor locality.  Today, with the
STL, you need a lot less code, and by using `std::vector` for all of the
lists, you get slightly better locality; you still have to be careful,
so that you don't end up saving iterators which will be invalidated.
(But implemented as described above, you shouldn't need to; all accesses
are always to the last element of the vector, so saving the address of
the vector itself is sufficient.  Provided, of course, that your hash
implementation doesn't move the vectors.)

Comment: Hi! It seems like this is also approachable by noobs like me. But I'm not so sure what you meant by symbol having entities. I get that symbols are, let's say (int i) i is symbol? but what does it mean by list entities? So far my guess is that each item in hash table, it stores symbol and two entities where it acts like a stack. One of them is from current scope and other ones from outer scope? Thank you for your details!!

Comment: @Kelly Song "Entity", here, is just anything the symbol can name.  In your example, variables, but in my case, it could also be functions, and in a more complicated language, types, etc.  So each entry in the hash map has a name (the symbol, which also acts as index), and an `std::vector<Entity>`, where `Entity` is the representation of whatever the symbol defines.

Answer (score 0):

This is an OK idea. In most languages, scopes are rarely nested very deeply, perhaps an average of 3 or 4 nested scopes. So I wouldn't worry about things that are "far, far away", as these will be pathological cases.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to worry about it because there will be few hundreds, or thousand scopes to test this program.

Comment: @Kelly Say what? I have never, ever seen such a thing. Remember, you only maintain a scope as long as it is active.